# Unable to parse some Umm Al-Qura dates in java, getting Invalid Hijrah day of month error

Tags: java, java-time, hijri

I am trying to parse below date in java using normal, hijri and Ummalqura calenders but everytime getting the same exception as below

Date: **"30-02-1405"** or **"30-12-1419"**

DateTimeException: Invalid Hijrah day of month: 30

Note: There are many other date which are causing the same issue.

To me, it seems like i am not able to pass the calendar type correctly to the calender function. Can anyone help me parsing these dates.

Below are the code i tried

```
// Using the msarhan ummalqura-calendar library

Locale en = Locale.ENGLISH;
        
UmmalquraCalendar calnow = new UmmalquraCalendar(en);

calnow.set(1419, UmmalquraCalendar.THUL_HIJJAH, 30);
        
System.out.println(calnow.getTime());
```

```
// Using Java time HijrahChronology

HijrahDate dateOfBirthHijri = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(1405, 2, 30);
```

Comment: If you want the last day of the month, you may use`HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(1405, 2, 1) .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())` with java.time. The example yields `Hijrah-umalqura AH 1405-02-29`.

Answer (score 1):

`THUL_HIJJAH` (December) (year 1419) and `SAFAR` (February) (year 1405) has only 29 days .

So, the dates: "**30-02-1405**", "**30-12-1419**" are invalid. Use **29th** day instead.

Update to this:

```
    Locale en = Locale.ENGLISH;

    UmmalquraCalendar calnow = new UmmalquraCalendar(en);

    calnow.set(1419, UmmalquraCalendar.THUL_HIJJAH, 29);

    System.out.println(calnow.getTime());
```

Or

```
HijrahDate dateOfBirthHijri = HijrahChronology.INSTANCE.date(1405, 2, 29);
System.out.println(dateOfBirthHijri);
```

Output:

```
> Task :Example.main()
Fri Apr 16 19:03:34 IST 1999
Hijrah-umalqura AH 1405-02-29
```

Comment: The data source of Date is government data and these are the date of birth of people.,and if you check the below website, the 30th day exists.

https://datehijri.com/en/hijri30-12-1419togregorianconverter.html

Comment: Anish, It's just the spelling difference or maybe the pronunciation difference, other than that THUL_HIJJAH is the same as Dhu al-Hijjah which is the 12th and last month

Comment: @HamzaFarooq Yeah! You are right. My Bad. :) I didn't recognize it.